# Try running MyCrypto with my local node!

Tags: parity, mycrypto

i want connect my local parity nodes with Mycrypto i flowed this tutorial to built my two nodes https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial.html
than i try to flow this tutorial to connect it to Mycrypto https://support.mycrypto.com/networks/run-your-own-node-with-mycrypto.html

im still straggling with connect my nodes to Mycrypto i need some help plz 
both my nodes work fine in terminals and they connected together and have users addresses and i can send eth from one to another fine by terminals.

so what is chain ID i tryed to add Enode URL and its not work i dont know how to connect that

thank you

[image]